# I have a list of names and have to return the amount of each name in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this list:
`[michelle,michelle,sara,jorge,sara,marie]`
I need to return a list like this
`[[michelle,2],[sara,2],[jorge,1],[marie,1]]`
I thought about doing something with two `for();` but don't know how to do it. Can someone guide me? Thanks in advance.

```
for(int i=0;names[i]!=NULL;i++){
        for (int j=0;names[j]!=NULL;j++){
            if(names[i]==names[j]){

            }
```

Comment: Just use `while`...

Comment: I don't understand how to do a list like this [[name1,count1],[name2,count2]]

Answer (score -1):

```
int i,j;
i=0;
while (name[i++]!=NULL){
    j=0;
    while (name[j++]!=NULL){
        /* whatever */
    }
}
```

would do the same thing as the for loop.
In fact, one can just do

```
int i=0,j,ptr=0,flag;
char strlist[NUMBER_OF_STRING][LENGTH_OF_STRING];
int count[NUMBER_OF_STRING];
while (name[i++]!=NULL){
    j=flag=0;
    while (j++<ptr){
        if (strcmp(name[i],strlist[j])){
            flag=1;
            count[j]++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!flag){
        strcpy(strlist[ptr],name[i]);
        count[ptr]=1;
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, does the same, but how do you create a list like this? [[something1,count_of_something1],[something2,count_of_something2]] being something1 and something2 things that are repeated in a list [something1,something2,something1,something2,something2]

Comment: @cde33 see edit, (but don't copy and paste this piece of code)